# mod_rewrite directives work in .htaccess but ignored in httpd.conf

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, debian

struggling with mod_rewrite in apache2. Problem is that the directives are ignored when put into the httpd.conf.

If I set `AllowOverride All` in the sites-available/default and add the directive to .htaccess it works and each request pops up in the mod_rewrite.log.

But when I remove the .htaccess and the `AllowOverride All` and add the directive to the httpd.conf it's ignored.

Httpd.conf looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/mod_rewrite.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 4 
    RewriteRule ^/.* http://www.google.com                                     
</IfModule>
```

(Just chose google for debugging)

Phpinfo() shows mod_rewrite among the loaded modules, rewrite.load is is symlinked at /mods-enabled to mods-available, i.e., it is really there. Also, when I delete the mod_rewrite.log it is created on server start-up what IMO indicates that httpd.conf is read and mod_rewrite.c exists. But the mod_rewrite.log stays blank which would indicate that no request is sent to mod_rewrite. Additionally, when putting nonsense into the httpd.conf server won't start and throws an error.

What am I missing? Is there something like `AllowOverride` I have to set even for main config files?

I already played around with the `/` as .htaccess uses relative paths and httpd.conf doesn't. I also tried setting `<Directory>` tags, which does not make sense for me but still tried it to see if it changes anything ... help?!

---

Figured it out myself but in case someone runs into the same problem:

'Global' Rewrite-rules set in the httpd.conf have to be included in each virtual host using

```
<VitualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteOptions Inherit
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise they won't work in the VHosts. Also, the parent rules are applied AFTER the child rules.